# How would i route through a NAT router to a virtual machine only?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

i have a basic home network setup of modem plugged into basic dhcp router that will allow port forwarding.  I want to route to maybe port 80 or 8080 if possible, so that an ubuntu-server-virtualbox web-server is accessible to the WAN.
Does this pose any risk to the host machine?
 Is this possible with a host-only adapter (through host files)?
 And if i must change it to NAT, do i need to change the host file on both machines? Could i get an example if the host looks like 10.0.2.2 (192.168.1.2 to the rest of LAN), the virtual-machine has 10.0.2.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host Only will work with a bit of tweaking if you know how to set up routing.

The easiest would be to use Bridged Mode - the network sees the virtual machine as just another machine on the network - by far the simplest method.

And no, it poses no risk to the host machine.